# Retrive image from nsdata NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsmutablearray, xcode4.5, nsdata

i add image in `NSMutableArray` than i convert it in `NSData` and agaun i store that image in other `NSMutableArray`. But when i convert back to image that give me Error

my Code is

```
NSData *Puzzleimage;
PuzzleImg = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
TriangleImg = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[PuzzleImg addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Triangle_1.png"]];
    [PuzzleImg addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Triangle_2.png"]];
    [PuzzleImg addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Triangle_3.png"]];
    [PuzzleImg addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Triangle_4.png"]];
    [PuzzleImg addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Triangle_5.png"]];


    for (int l=0; l<[PuzzleImg count]; l++) {
        Puzzleimage = UIImagePNGRepresentation([PuzzleImg objectAtIndex:l]);
        [TriangleImg addObject:Puzzleimage];
```

**Retrive in Scroll View**

```
 CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(10, 60, 300, 350);
        PuzzleList = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
        [self.view addSubview:PuzzleList];

        int y1=10;
        int y2=10;
        if ([PuzzleImg count] >0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<[PuzzleImg count];i++)
            {
                    UIImage *SolImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[PuzzleImg objectAtIndex:i]];
                    UIButton *btn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y1, 100, 100)];
                    [btn setBackgroundImage:SolImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    btn.tag = i;
                    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(SelectPuzzleButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                    [PuzzleList addSubview:btn];
                    y1=y1+110;
         }
}
```

**Error is**
*The error is display on Line ::UIImage *SolImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[PuzzleImg objectAtIndex:i]];*

-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1bc690
2013-04-10 10:41:47.292 CreativeLogic[2791:1a003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1bc690'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2612012 0x1422e7e 0x269d4bd 0x2601bbc 0x260194e 0x4cf1b2 0x38c1f3 0xc1d7 0xaac3 0xa532 0x44b817 0x44b882 0x44bb2a 0x462ef5 0x462fdb 0x463286 0x463381 0x463eab 0x4644a3 0x464098 0xe255 0x1436705 0x36d920 0x36d8b8 0x42e671 0x42ebcf 0x42dd38 0x39d33f 0x39d552 0x37b3aa 0x36ccf8 0x28fedf9 0x28fead0 0x2587bf5 0x2587962 0x25b8bb6 0x25b7f44 0x25b7e1b 0x28fd7e3 0x28fd668 0x36a65c 0x2022 0x1f55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: it is nsdata please see my update Thanks

Comment: Are you sending `TriangleImg` to the second code segment or only `PuzzleImg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change from this ...

```
UIImage *SolImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[PuzzleImg objectAtIndex:i]];
```

to ...

```
UIImage *SolImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[TriangleImg objectAtIndex:i]];
```

I think this is enough for you

Answer (score 0):

See you add `UIImage` as a `NSData` in `TriangleImg` `NSMutableArray` object not in `PuzzleImg` `NSMutableArray` object  so use bellow line

```
UIImage *SolImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[TriangleImg objectAtIndex:i]];
```

instead of this bellow line...

```
UIImage *SolImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[PuzzleImg objectAtIndex:i]];
```